# Obtain Spring and other framework version numbers in a JVM

Tags: java, spring, frameworks, version, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to create a 'skeleton' framework of sorts for a basic java app.

One thing I'm looking to add is a version page/display that list the current framework/libs attached.

For example:

Skeleton version: 1.0.0
Spring: 2.5.6
Hibernate: Malbolge

The purpose of the Skeleton project was to make it very easy for a new developer to quickly start a robust app.
I figured the worst case scenario is that I could search through every framework jars manifest and use that... but that's no fun...

Anyone have a different suggestion?  This would be a no brainer if the project was going to use Maven... I could just parse the pom.xml or something to that extent...

I guess a more defined question is:

Given a folder of libs; is there a way to dynamically gather the jars/frameworks version # without touching the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the Spring version using the [SpringVersion class](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/SpringVersion.html).

I had a code snippet in a previous question:

[Need Spring version# - only have spring.jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947586/need-spring-version-only-have-spring-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

Using [System.getProperties()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) gives you a listing of JVM properties including the different version ids of the JRE, JVM and specification. Not sure if this will give Spring etc versions.