# Is there any way to tell what version of Spring I have?

Tags: java, spring

I have inherited a Java web app that uses the Spring framework. I know that it is pretty dated but I cannot find out what version of Spring it uses. All Spring files don't have any version number so are named such as spring-core.jar. Also the date/time stamp doesn't help as that is from this year.

Is there any reliable way to determine the Spring version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947586/need-spring-version-only-have-spring-jar-file

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Let me know if you got your answer.

```
import org.springframework.core.SpringVersion;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("version: " + SpringVersion.getVersion());
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the checksum method outlined in the link to the duplicate post.